# Correct use of arrayBaseOffset and arrayIndexScale

Tags: java, arrays, unsafe

I have defined a simple array and I want to use `Unsafe.arrayBaseOffset` and `Unsafe.arrayIndexScale` with the following snippet.

```
import sun.misc.Unsafe;
public class Arr
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int [] a = new int[3];
    a[0] = 10; a[1] = 20; a[2] = 30;
    int baseOffset = Unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(a.getClass());
    int indexScale = Unsafe.arrayIndexScale(a.getClass());
  }
}
```

However I get these errors

```
Arr.java:11: non-static method arrayBaseOffset(java.lang.Class) cannot be referenced from a static context
    int baseOffset = Unsafe.arrayBaseOffset(a.getClass());
                           ^

Arr.java:12: non-static method arrayIndexScale(java.lang.Class) cannot be referenced from a static context
    int indexScale = Unsafe.arrayIndexScale(a.getClass());
                           ^
```

Comment: Have you tried referencing the fully qualified object name. i.e `sun.misc.Unsafe`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `arrayBaseOffset` and `arrayIndexScale` methods are not static, so you cannot call them the way you are.  You need to do it like this:

```
    Unsafe u = Unsafe.getUnsafe();
    int baseOffset = u.arrayBaseOffset(a.getClass());
    int indexScale = u.arrayIndexScale(a.getClass());
```